# Legend key position in Excel

Tags: excel, office365

Is there a way to change the position on the legend key in an excel chart?
Instead of being on the right of the symbol, I want it to be on the left.

for example:
instead of:

---

• something

---

I want it to be:

---

something •

Comment: I don't believe there is. I've been through the LegendEntry class and the LegendKey class in VBA and there is no option there (at least nothing that sounds even remotely close to this).

Comment: Ok.. thank you for trying to help, JNebvill!